# ASP.net core Web API post array as a property

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I use an array to store tags of question, but when i POST data from Chrome i do not receive any data on TagId Array.
Other Properties are OK and i receive them onlu TagId is `null`
Here is my Code:

**Question.cs**

```
public partial class Question 
{

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    ...

    [Display(Name = "Tags")]
    [NotMapped]
    public int[] TagId
    {
      get
      {
          Some Code Here
      }

      set
      {
        Tag = "";
        if(value==null)
          return;
        foreach (var i in value)
        {
          Tag = i + ",";
        }

        Tag = Tag.Trim(',');
      }
    }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public string Tag { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Here is chrome post with dummy data [Chrome post Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bH3tQ.png)
and i receive null in asp.net Post Data: [Visual Studio Trace on Data receive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xRB6.png)

here is my controller post code:

**QuestionsController.cs**

```
[Route("adminapi/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class QuestionsController : BaseRControllerWithFile<Question,QuestionAdminRepository>
{
...
  public override async Task<ActionResult<Question>> Post(Question entity)
  {
    return await base.Post(entity);
  }
...
}
```

Comment: Other than TagId, does it getting bind?

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue and found, that the `value` was indeed `null` when the `Question` object is deserialized, but only on the first call. Can you confirm that it is set to the correct value afterwards?

Comment: **On a side note:** You can use `string.Join(",", value)` instead of concatenating the tag ids with a loop.

Comment: @PaulKertscher; string.Join has an inner loop.

Comment: @XAMT Of course it has, but using `string.Join` more concise and clearer, hence I don't see why you shouldn't use it in this case.

Comment: @PrashantPimpale every thing works good! only tagId is null and as you can see [here][https://i.stack.imgur.com/bH3tQ.png] other tagId is also set but i cant receive it in server side

Comment: @PaulKertscher no every time i test it with different data i receive null! even i used PUT instead of POST and again i received null!

Comment: @mehregan Could you create a simple [mcve]? I created a Web API (Core 3.1) and added a class just with the `TagId` and `Tag` properties. Both with `POST` and `PUT` the value is set **but** before `TagId` is set to the correct value, it is set to `null` once.

Answer (score 0):

Change the Question class to this :

```
public class Question
{
    private int[] tagId;

    private string tag;

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Tags")]
    [NotMapped]
    public int[] TagId
    {
        get => tagId;
        set
        {
            tagId = value;

            tag = "";
            if (value == null)
                return;
            foreach (var i in tagId)
            {
                tag += i + ",";
            }

            tag = tag.Trim(',');
        }
    }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public string Tag => tag;
}
```

Or as @Paul said; you can use Join :

```
tag = value != null ? string.Join(',', tagId) : null;
```